# Time Series Examples ARIMA

Tags: time-series, arima

I am very new to this topic named "Time Series ARIMA". I have tried to google it but the results are not fruitful.Can any one please suggest a **online source** WHERE i can get a complete  CONCEPTUAL understanding and interpretation. I don't want to get complicated through math formulae and all. I just want to know the interpretation

Comment: You *cannot hope* to get a *complete* understanding without at least some mathematics. Indeed without mathematics, any understanding would be very fragile, because it would have no foundation; a slight change in any aspect of it would leave you floundering to comprehend it (consider a fairly straightforward issue like *what happens to the autocorrelation function if this parameter goes up and that one goes down?* - a fairly routine exercise, and one capable of some form of answer if you carry through some algebra, but nigh unanswerable if you have only intuitive descriptions to go on). ... ctd

Comment: ctd...  Any reference that's of any value at all (i.e. even one conveying a good partial understanding) will need at least some mathematics; one without any - if you can find one at all - will typically be worse than useless.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24398/online-material-to-learn-time-series-analysis ... some of the references [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20514/books-for-self-studying-time-series-analysis) are on-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Forecasting: principles and practice](https://www.otexts.org/fpp) by Rob Hyndman and George Athana­sopou­los [1] is my reference. It's free and good.

[1] Hyndman, R.J. and Athanasopoulos, G. (2013)
*Forecasting: principles and practice*.
OTexts: Melbourne, Australia.
http://otexts.org/fpp/. Accessed on 11 April 2017.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a proper reference, as given [here](https://www.otexts.org/about/book-citation)